# Given a subgroup $H\le G$ and an element $g\in G$, is $H\cap gHg^{-1}$ normalized by $g$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H\le G$ a subgroup, and $g\in G$ an element. Must $g$ normalize $H\cap gHg^{-1}$?

This is true if $H\le G$ is cyclic and finite index, but I don't see if the proof can be extended to a more general case.

**Proof in the case that $H = \langle h\rangle$ is cyclic and finite index in $G$:** =
In this case, $H\cap gHg^{-1}$ is also cyclic, with the same (finite) index in both $H$ and $gHg^{-1}$, so let $x$ be a generator. It suffices to show that $gxg^{-1}\in H$.

For some integers $i,j$, we have $x = h^i = gh^jg^{-1}$. On the other hand, $gxg^{-1} = gh^ig^{-1}$, but
$$[gHg^{-1} : \langle gh^ig^{-1}\rangle] = [H : \langle x\rangle] = [H : H\cap gHg^{-1}] = [gHg^{-1}:H\cap gHg^{-1}] = [gHg^{-1}:\langle x\rangle] = [gHg^{-1} : \langle gh^jg^{-1}\rangle]$$
which implies that $\langle gh^ig^{-1}\rangle = \langle gh^jg^{-1}\rangle$ by uniqueness of subgroups of cyclic groups of a given index. This implies that $gh^ig^{-1}\in\langle x\rangle\in H$, as desired.

Comment: This is false in general, say for free groups $G$.

Comment: This is false for most finite groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example.
Take as $G$ the group $S_5$ and as $H$ the subgroup $S_4$ of $S_5$. Let x=(125).
Then we obtain $H^x\cap H=\{e,(23),(24),(34),(234),(243)\}=K$ and
$(152)(23)(125)=(13)\notin K$.